# c# Buttons as toggles

Tags: c#, winforms

Hello i am new in C# and need some help

In both `groupboxes` have buttons they are now like `toggle butons`, but now can i choose only one button from all.

looking for:

- clik `one` from `Groupbox1`, `one` from `Groupbox2`
- `clicked buttons` will have `green` `background`
- after press `OK` show messagebox with `button name` `GB2 + " - " GB1`

....................................................

Another question:

Buttons 1-6 can be added as `dynamic buttons` directly from `SQL`?

From `Sql` need have `ID` and `Name`

....................................................

[image]

Comment: Is this WPF, Winforms, or something else?

Comment: @AidanHorton Clearly WinForms.

Comment: winform, you have right i want it too :)

Comment: @jAC I'm not aware of the names of elements in Winforms - don't be patronizing.

Comment: @Jcl Ahahahah, one of the best comments i have ever read.

Comment: @jAC It might be clear to you, but OP should specify it when they ask a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just some hints:

- Use a [`RadioButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx) with Appearance set to `Button`.
- Check the [Remarks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.aspx#Remarks) of the radio button to find out how to make two groups.
- Subscribe to `CheckedChanged` event and set `BackColor` according to value in `Checked` property.
- To dynamically insert buttons, take a look into designer.cs file. You can create your own buttons exactly the same way at runtime by doing the same stuff in your own method which you call whenever needed with desired parameters.
- For the message box message check the state of all radio buttons and take the name from the box where `Checked` is true. (Advanced users would filter the `Controls` property for the desired type and value by using LINQ).

If you have started all of these and have a more concrete question: Ask a new question for **one problem**. Don't hope to ask one question containing all your questions and get a working example back.

Comment: RadioButton is ok, after set the AutoSize property to false, can i resize it,,,,